# Не работает UITapGestureRecognizer в UITableViewCell

Tags: swift

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Не работает GestureRecognizer для картинка размещенной в ячейке. Срабатывает только didSelectRowAt этой ячейки.
Подскажите, пожалуйста как это можно исправить.

Краткий код ячейки:

class NotificationCell: UITableViewCell {

```
private lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.setDimensions(width: 40, height: 40)
    iv.backgroundColor = .twitterBlue
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 40 / 2
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfileImageTapped))
    iv.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return iv
}()

@objc func handleProfileImageTapped() {
    print("DEBUG: check tapped image")
}
```

}

Краткий код контроллера:

```
class NotificationsController: UITableViewController {
extension NotificationsController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("DEBUG: check tapped cell")
    }
}
```

}

таблица с ячейками зарегистрирована правильно.

Comment: Вангую, у вас хитТест селектор в таргете не находит. Попробуйте убрать таргет UITapGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: #selector(handleProfileImageTapped))

Comment: Наверняка. Но удаление не помогло.

Comment: Тогда скорее всего дело в lazy, переменная будет создана лениво (тогда, когда к ней обратятся), а тап к ней уже не подцепится, попробуйте обойтись без lazy.

Comment: Результат тот же

Comment: Выложите куда-нибудь проект, посмотрю, если хотите.

Comment: https://github.com/wasaw/Twi в папке View\NotificationCell Спасибо.

Comment: Замените addSubview(stack) на self.contentView.addSubview(stack) и addSubview(followButton) на self.contentView.addSubview(followButton). У вас таргеты добавлялись не на вью ячейки.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените addSubview(stack) на self.contentView.addSubview(stack) и addSubview(followButton) на self.contentView.addSubview(followButton). У вас таргеты добавлялись не на вью ячейки.